# How to exit entire test run after retries fail in Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

Selenium tests take a long time to run. How can I configure Nightwatch to exit the entire test run if the retries of a failed test case all fail? None of the configuration options seem to provide this functionality.

Comment: `skip_testcases_on_fail`?

Comment: That only skips the current suite, not the entire run.